# toHuman() but with regular numbers

Tags: polkadot-js

The `toHuman()` call on Types casts numbers into formatted strings and rounds currency values.

I would like to store large amounts of block information in human-readable format, but not lose the precision of numbers or have them casted into strings.

Is there a way to enjoy the benefits of human-readable objects without having numbers cast into strings and precision lost?

Comment: Can we have some more context? What language are you using? Is this the JavaScript polkadot API or some other API?

Comment: I am referring to vanilla Polkadot.js

Comment: maybe `toHex()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `toPrimitive` instead and you will get a JS number (when < 2^53 -1) or a string value when it is larger.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/2c949e0fc58ce5b113f3d07045468ae153743bdb/packages/types/src/extrinsic/Extrinsic.spec.ts#L46) of it being used to decode an extrinsic. You can see the numbers are not formatted as strings.

If having numbers cast to strings is an issue then use `toHex`.

Comment: Thanks @forgetso - I'm afraid I need to clarify a part of my question. I tried toPrimitive(), but the issue there is that I'm missing some human-readable parts, like section/method information in an extrinsic. In the toPrimitive() variant, it only gives me the method index.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your type being formatted? Perhaps sharing the bytes and type may help if it is a common type.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by monkey patching the `toHuman()` method of `AbstractInt`. Now I can call `toHuman()` on any object and all nested ints will convert the way I need them. Not a clean solution, but in my case it does the job.

```
import {AbstractInt} from "@polkadot/types-codec/abstract/Int";


AbstractInt.prototype.toHuman = function (isExpanded?: boolean): any {
    if(this.bitLength() <= 64) {
        return this.toPrimitive();
    }
    return this.toBn().toString();
};
```